# Splitting IntelliJ/Maven project into several components

Tags: java, visual-studio, maven, intellij-idea

Coming from the C#/Visual Studio world, I can do the following:

1. Create a Solution 'S'
2. Create a new library project 'L'
3. Create a main project 'M'
4. Add a reference to library 'L' into 'M'

-> Whenever I change the code in 'L', I can use the changes in 'M', given that the projects compile sequentially.
The library 'L' has its own independent code with its own logic and boundaries, and can be switched later to a web service.

How can I do the same in IntelliJ? ie reference a .JAR created from the same project?
Modules? Libraries?

Thanks

Comment: Create two modules, and create dependency .. then you can  create separate jars as well

Comment: Use the Maven parent pom and 2 child modules with the dependencies between them. When using SNAPSHOT dependencies, IntelliJ IDEA will resolve them via the sources and you will have IntelliJ IDEA modules created automatically. See the related discussion at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002826860-How-to-load-maven-dependency-from-another-project .